# Disabling location sharing on Android breaks Bluetooth discovery?

Tags: android, bluetooth, mdm, device-policy-manager

I have a DevicePolicyManager app that enforces the user restriction `DISALLOW_SHARE_LOCATION`. What I noticed is that Bluetooth stops discovering devices when the restriction is enforced. In the logcat output, I found some messages:

```
09-27 09:09:16.564 629-676/system_process W/BroadcastQueue: Appop Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND flg=0x10 (has extras) } to ProcessRecord{c929e01 1066:com.android.systemui/u0a15} (pid=1066, uid=10015) requires appop android:coarse_location due to sender com.android.bluetooth (uid 1002)
```

It seems like Bluetooth discovery is tied to `android:coarse_location`? Which `DISALLOW_SHARE_LOCATION` disables, as far as I know. Is there a workaround to this?